# Как изменить IBLOCK_TITLE в форме?

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть форма на битриксе, js работает через jqm,  хочу разобраться как её правильно редактировать:

сама кнопка

```html
 <span class="" data-event="jqm" data-param-id="19" data name="services">
  <a href="#" class="small_reference-others">Заказать образец</a>
</span>
```

вот кусок шаблона который отвечает за вывод шапки формы

```html
<div class="text">
  <?if( $arResult[ "isIblockTitle"] ){?>
    <div class="title">
      <?=$arResult[ "IBLOCK_TITLE"]?>
    </div>
    <?}?>
      <?if( $arResult[ "isIblockDescription"] ){ if( $arResult[ "IBLOCK_DESCRIPTION_TYPE"]=="text" ){?>
        <p>
          <?=$arResult[ "IBLOCK_DESCRIPTION"]?>
        </p>
        <?}else{?>
          <?=$arResult[ "IBLOCK_DESCRIPTION"]?>
            <?} }?>
</div>
```

[скриншот формы](https://yadi.sk/i/kg4RH-lZuZo3r)

т.е я хочу изменить название , титл формы, я так понимаю он берет из названия инфоблока, я соответственно меняю тут [чек](https://yadi.sk/i/9MIWwaC6uZoKK), но название так и остается "заказать услугу", я могу конечно переписать вот так шаблон

```
> <div class="title">Заказать образец</div>
```

Но хочу понять почему не меняется  **`<?=$arResult[ "IBLOCK_TITLE"]?>`**

Comment: а кэш почистили? Попробуйте очистить кэш и проверьте. Если не меняется пишите аспро в поддержку.

Comment: @НиколайСарры да конечно чистил) да у аспро разговор короткий, обновите шаблон, обновите битрикс, потом пишите) а для этого надо заплатить , во вторых если обновить их шаблон то слетит куча изменений, сделанных до меня, а выиискивать их дело не из приятных)

Comment: да этим аспро отличаются. Хм только что проверял на нашем тестовом аспровском сайте все работает отлично.